# Get number of iteration in a binary search

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I am trying to implement a binary search function that returns the index of an element and the number of iteration(s) it took to get the element.

```
function binarySearch(array, number) {
    var obj = {}, index, count = 0;
    var start = 0;
    var end = array.length - 1;
    var middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    while(array[middle] !== number && start <= end) {
        if(number < array[middle]) end = middle - 1;
        else start = middle + 1;
        middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    }

    array[middle] === number ? obj.index = middle : obj.index = -1;
    obj.count++
    return obj;
}
```

I expected output of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], 3`. to be `obj = {index:2, count:3}` but am getting `obj ={index;2, count:NaN}`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `count: NaN` because you never initialized `obj.count`. Adding 1 to an undefined value produces `NaN`.

You need to increment `count` in the loop. Then at the end you can assign `obj.count = count;`

And if you're going to use a ternary expression, do it in the source of the assignment, rather than repeating the assignment in each condition.

```js
function binarySearch(array, number) {
  var obj = {},
    index, count = 0;
  var start = 0;
  var end = array.length - 1;
  var middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

  while (array[middle] !== number && start <= end) {
    if (number < array[middle]) end = middle - 1;
    else start = middle + 1;
    middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    count++;
  }

  obj.index = array[middle] === number ? middle : -1;
  obj.count = count;
  return obj;
}

console.log(binarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], 3));
```